# Using groupby() for a dataframe in pandas resulted Index Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this `dataframe`:

```
      x        y        z        parameter     
0     26       24       25       Age
1     35       37       36       Age  
2     57       52       54.5     Age
3     160      164      162      Hgt           
4     182      163      172.5    Hgt             
5     175      167      171      Hgt              
6     95       71       83       Wgt     
7     110      68       89       Wgt     
8     89       65       77       Wgt
```

I'm using `pandas` to get this **final result**:

```
      x        y        parameter     
0     160      164      Hgt           
1     182      163      Hgt             
2     175      167      Hgt
```

I'm using `groupby()` to extract and isolate rows based on same parameter **Hgt** from the original `dataframe`

First, I added a column to set it as an `index`:

`df = df.insert(0,'index', [count for count in range(df.shape[0])], True)`

And the `dataframe` came out like this:

```
      index    x        y        z        parameter     
0     0        26       24       25       Age
1     1        35       37       36       Age  
2     2        57       52       54.5     Age
3     3        160      164      162      Hgt           
4     4        182      163      172.5    Hgt             
5     5        175      167      171      Hgt              
6     6        95       71       83       Wgt     
7     7        110      68       89       Wgt     
8     8        89       65       77       Wgt
```

Then, I used the following code to group based on `index` and extract the columns I need:

`df1 = df.groupby('index')[['x', 'y','parameter']]`

And the output was:

```
      x        y        parameter     
0     26       24       Age
1     35       37       Age  
2     57       52       Age
3     160      164      Hgt           
4     182      163      Hgt             
5     175      167      Hgt              
6     95       71       Wgt     
7     110      68       Wgt     
8     89       65       Wgt
```

After that, I used the following code to isolate only **Hgt** values:

`df2 = df1[df1['parameter'] == 'Hgt']`

When I ran `df2`, I got an error saying:

`IndexError: Column(s) ['x', 'y', 'parameter'] already selected`

Am I missing something here? What to do to get the **final result**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you asked what you did wrong, let me point to useless/bad code.

Without any judgement (this is just to help you improve future code), almost everything is incorrect. It feels like a succession of complicated ways to do useless things. Let me give some details:

```
df = df.insert(0,'index', [count for count in range(df.shape[0])], True)
```

This seems a very convoluted way to do `df.reset_index()`. Even `[count for count in range(df.shape[0])]` could be have been simplified by using `range(df.shape[0])` directly.

But this step is not even needed for a `groupby` as you can group by index level:

```
df.groupby(level=0)
```

But... the `groupby` is useless anyways as you only have single membered groups.

Also, when you do:

```
df1 = df.groupby('index')[['x', 'y','parameter']]
```

`df1` is **not** a dataframe but a `DataFrameGroupBy` object. Very useful to store in a variable when you know what you're doing, this is however causing the error in your case as you thought this was a `DataFrame`. You need to apply an aggregation or transformation method of the `DataFrameGroupBy` object to get back a `DataFrame`, which you didn't (likely because, as seen above, there isn't much interesting to do on single-membered groups).

So when you run:

```
df1[df1['parameter'] == 'Hgt']
```

again, all is wrong as `df1['parameter']` is equivalent to `df.groupby('index')[['x', 'y','parameter']]['parameter']` (the cause of the error as you select twice 'parameter'). Even if you removed this error, the equality comparison would give a single `True`/`False` as you still have your `DataFrameGroupBy` and not a `DataFrame`, and this would incorrectly try to subselect an inexistent column of the `DataFrameGroupBy`.

I hope it helped!

Comment: It does help. Thank you very much! From people like you, we learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need `groupby`?

```
>>> df.loc[df['parameter'] == 'Hgt', ['x', 'y', 'parameter']].reset_index(drop=True)
     x    y parameter
0  160  164       Hgt
1  182  163       Hgt
2  175  167       Hgt
```

Comment: With your answer? I guess not! Thank you very much!
Let's say, I need to use `groupby()` to my dataframe. Would you kindly show me what did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't know why you need to use `groupby`. Take the time to read the excellent explanation of @mozway.